# Get first character of each line in text file

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file with names of customers. I need the first character of each line in the batch file. I made this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=c:\klantenlijst.txt
FOR /F "delims=~" %%i IN (%file%) DO (
  set var=%%i:~0,2
  echo !var!
)
```

But this results in the whole name, not just the first character, what is wrong?

Comment: First suggestion: don't use a .bat file.  Use WSH/VBScript, Powershell, ActivePerl - *anything* but a .bat file.  IMHO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set file=c:\klantenlijst.txt
FOR /F "delims=~" %%i IN (%file%) DO (
  set var=%%i
  set var=!var:~0,1!
  echo !var!
)
```

You can't do string manipulations with for loop variables.